# Some USB cables work, and some don't - why?

Tags: usb

Connecting a PC to a board with USB i/f. Some (2m) cable work OK and some don't. The obvious reason being that probably signals are marginal.

The board is powered from the USB, and takes around 200mA. Symptoms are typically "USB not recognized".

However, the immediate question is this: Why would two different USB cables have different responses and how can I choose ones that work. What parameters am I looking for?

I have just come across [this PDF document](http://www.gbs-elektronik.de/fileadmin/download/manuals/TN_Choosing_USB_Cable.pdf):

Comment: You should probably define what [doesn't work] means. What are you using it for? What are the symptoms of [doesn't work]?

Comment: Wire guage in case it consumes power and characteristic impedance for the data transfer. Other factors come into play too like sheilding.

Comment: And some "USB" cables only carry power, and not data.  Typically these come with devices as charging cables.

Comment: Updating the info

Comment: *Why would two different USB cables have different responses* Obviously not all USB cables are created equally. Some have very thin conductors causing voltage drop if you power your board through them. Do you power your board through the USB cable ? Then this might be your issue. I have seen USB cables through which I cannot fast charge my phone. Using the right (better quality) cable I can.

Comment: Some cables are bad, some are good....

Comment: Looks like it may well be voltage drop. Which leads me to the next question - do manufacturers specify resistance of the power-gnd?

Comment: *do manufacturers specify resistance of the power-gnd?* Some might, many don't. I have only seen conductor thickness being specified (as in that document) for certain cables (the more expensive, better ones) but not resistance values.

Comment: Many cables have the wire gauge printed on them. Its your decision as to whether or not you trust this information enough to use it to calculate the resistance.

Comment: Going to order some and experiment.

Comment: Anyway, the answer appears to be that 47pF caps to gnd on the data lines were too high. Now reduced to 22p and the problem disappears. I would guess that the differences in cable were due to the capacitance of the cable

So, yes - turns out it was a design problem. I would include more, but the subject is closed, and I'm OK!

Comment: @PlasmaHH: Some "a devices with USB i/f" are good, some are bad...